# Windows 10 wifi adapter will not start

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, windows-10

So I have upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10, all seem fine except I got no wifi, it does not even show up under network options. I went to device manger and it show me this [image][image]
worked fine in windows 7 but not 10, I connected right now through Ethernet, I tried to update the drivers but it says they are up to date, tried to diagnose the problem but it says everything is fine, I tried to find the manufactures site but I cant. My guess is that they haven't updated the drivers yet.
the wireless card itself has a part number of

HP P/N:5188-3742

Any help would be appreciated, I rather not go back to windows 7.

Comment: It's a Liteon WN5401, or WN5301 wireless adapter, is an older one from 2006 and earlier era, was used with XP originally. I doubt there is a W10 driver for it. Did you check the HP website to see if they have a newer driver than you have installed. http://support.hp.com/us-en

Comment: If you could post up the Hardware IDs of the device (the second picture you've posted, the "Details" tab) we'll be able to see if there are alternative packages that offer a Windows 8/10 driver...